# Parent form getting closed with show dialog in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms

I have a form lets say Form A and it has two buttons, OK and clear. On the Clear button a "OkCancel" dialog is shown.

When user clicks on ok or cancel button the Form A (which is parent of dialog form is getting closed. I have debugged it and I found that when user clicks on OK or Cancel form close event is raised so that Form A is getting closed. Can you explain why this is happening?

Comment: What is the call stack inside the parent form's `FormClosing` event?

Comment: seeing your code where you call `showdialog` and the buttons click events would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, the code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A form's accept and cancel buttons (`AcceptButton1` and `CancelButton` properties) will cause it to close if the form is displayed using `.showdialog`. You can prevent this with the Accept button by setting the `DialogResult` property to "none".

Comment: AFAIK, that behavior is controlled by the buttons' `DialogResult` property

Comment: It is in the Accept button, but not in Cancel. Cancel closes whether DialogResult is "none" or "Cancel" (VB 2008).

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question -- it's hard to tell which form is being closed.